# How to know replicaset status from a mongos

Tags: mongodb, status, replicaset

I am trying to monitor a mongodb cluster with a full readOnly access on a mongos.

My problem today is that I have to know the exact status of a replica. With the command shardConnPoolStats I can know if the replica is primary or secondary, but i dont know what happend if a replica go down or something like that.

So I am looking for a command who could tell me it without connect to any mongod.

I can't try by myself to make a replica shutdown and see if the command shardConnPoolStats does display this information, because i have only read access.

Thank you for reading and i hope someone can answer fast.

Comment: To administer the individual replica sets, you'll want access to the actual replica sets, not just read access through the mongos.